# Invalid type: sequence, expected a string for key 'rpc.cors'

Tags: parity, rpc, configuration

Trying to run parity using the configuration file `node.toml` file

```
$ parity --config /data/parity/node.toml
Loading config file from /data/parity/node.toml
You might have supplied invalid parameters in config file.
invalid type: sequence, expected a string for key `rpc.cors`
```

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file `node.toml` file,

```
[rpc]
cors=[]
```

For parity version 1.8.7-stable,
it expects a string.

Replaced by

```
cors="null"
```